# Switching iTunes App Store categories for iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

We're considering switching our app from one Apple App Store primary category (education) to another (business) and have three questions:

1. What's the impact, if any, on keyword rankings?
2. Right now we're listed as one of the most popular apps in the education career and professional subcategory. Will we lose that when we make the switch if education becomes our secondary (rather than primary) category?
3. If we're one of the top ranking apps for the keyword "career", how quickly can we expect to appear in the popular career apps under the business category?

Comment: Why don't try add a subcategory (business) and left unchanged your first category (education). If you are in the first places from education, you maybe does not move it, unless economics is not well and you don't have other option.

Comment: Our secondary category is already Business but it seems we can only rank in subcategories for the primary category? There are some subcategories in Business we'd really like to rank in the top 10 for, so we are considering switching our primary category to Business and making Education our secondary.

Comment: Sorry i don't read well. I hope someone answer this question, I'm interesting about it. I have a similar situation but I don't have important information to answer it.

Comment: May I ask why you have / want to change the category at all if you are high-ranked already?

Comment: Linus - we aren't ranked in any official App Store category. We are well-ranked for particular keywords. Switching categories might not affect keyword search rankings at all, but that is part of what we are trying to ascertain.